# Using ast.literal_eval on a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using ast.literal_eval to change the data I receive from json.loads() into a Python dictionary; however if I should just be going about this an entirely different way - feel free to point that out as well.

```
# Authentication
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "https://kippt.com/api/account")
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, header)
c.perform()

result = buf.getvalue()
buf.close()

print result

# Printing Output
data_string = json.dumps(result)
jsonload = json.loads(data_string)
jsondict = ast.literal_eval(jsonload)
```

Currently it works properly with a one line JSON return, eg:

{"username": "my_username", "api_token": "my_api_token"}

and I can get the values properly with:

```
print jsondict['username']
print jsondict['api_token']
```

The part where I'm having an issue with is when the data is nested, such as:

> {"meta": {"next": null, "total_count": 6, "previous": null, "limit":
>   20, "offset": 0}, "objects": [{"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/cool-stuff",
>   "updated": "1339003710", "title": "Cool Stuff", "created":
>   "1339001514", "slug": "cool-stuff", "id": 54533, "resource_uri":
>   "/api/lists/54533/"}, {"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/programming",
>   "updated": "1339003479", "title": "Programming", "created":
>   "1339001487", "slug": "programming", "id": 54532, "resource_uri":
>   "/api/lists/54532/"}, {"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/android",
>   "updated": "1339003520", "title": "Android", "created": "1339000936",
>   "slug": "android", "id": 54530, "resource_uri": "/api/lists/54530/"},
>   {"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/chrome",
>   "updated": "1339000931", "title": "Chrome", "created": "1339000412",
>   "slug": "chrome", "id": 54529, "resource_uri": "/api/lists/54529/"},
>   {"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/inbox",
>   "updated": "1338946730", "title": "Inbox", "created": "1338945940",
>   "slug": "inbox", "id": 54432, "resource_uri": "/api/lists/54432/"},
>   {"rss_url":
>   "https://kippt.com/feed/username_here/stuff_here/read-later",
>   "updated": "1338945940", "title": "Read Later", "created":
>   "1338945940", "slug": "read-later", "id": 54433, "resource_uri":
>   "/api/lists/54433/"}]}

When I use the same code (Exchange URL for /api/lists) then I get the following error upon running the script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kippt.py", line 48, in
>   
>       jsondict = ast.literal_eval(jsonload)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
>       return _convert(node_or_string)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
>       in zip(node.keys, node.values))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in 
>       return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
>       in zip(node.keys, node.values))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in 
>       return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
>       raise ValueError('malformed string') ValueError: malformed string

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

### Edit - Answer below:

Looks like my first input could have been interpretted as Python syntax, which is where my fault lay as I technically wasn't doing it the right way to begin with even with that.

I now just want to json.loads() my result from cURL rather than doing the screwy stuff I was doing before.

eg:

```
buf = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "https://kippt.com/api/lists")
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, header)
c.perform()

result = buf.getvalue()
buf.close()

print result

# Printing Output
jsonload = json.loads(result)
print jsonload['meta']['total_count'] # Gets the total_count item in the meta object.
```

Comment: There are some slight differences between JSON and Python syntax. You should use the json library to convert your string to a dict

Comment: @gnibbler, can you post an example?

Comment: Your question _is an example_ of the incompatibilities between JSON repr of a dict and Python's repr of the same dict

Comment: I meant an example on converting a JSON rep to a dictionary. I can't seem to find anything in the json library distinctly for it.

Comment: Scratch that, I looked into what @David Wolever was getting at a bit more, and changed things around - Will edit my OP to show what was done. Thanks.

Comment: @TJBiddle Kippt's developer here. Is there a real reason why you're using pycurl? If not, you should be using python-requests. It's provides way nicer APIs for working with Kippt's API

Comment: @jorde Was mainly using pycurl just to get experience with it. Switched to requests earlier though and it's *much* easier. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval` has no problem with nested dictionaries:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'a': {'b':'c'}}")
{'a': {'b': 'c'}}
```

`ast.literal_eval` is breaking because the data are, in fact, JSON… And JSON is not valid Python. Specifically, `null` is not a valid Python literal.

Why not just use `json.loads()` to load the data?

Comment: Hm, well how do I reference the data then? I'm using json.loads() already if you take a quick look at the second to last line in my first code block. Thanks for the example by the way.

Comment: Ah, alright. So looks like I wanted to load the result directly. I thought the way I was doing it was kind of quirky - but it worked for the other example so figured it was correct. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Also, if you're doing HTTP stuff, you'll almost definitely be happier using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thanks! I had seen a few posts regarding that but finally gave it a try, it's a lot nicer - thanks!

Comment: json.loads does not work with single quoted keys.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one scenario where in I wanted to use json.normalize in pandas but values were of str type. using ast.literal_eval, i type casted

You can use ast.literal_eval like below -
df[column_name] = df[column_name].apply(ast.literal_eval)

this will convert str to dict.
for eg.
df = [{'A': "{'value': '1'}", 'B': "{'value': '2'}"}]

after applying literal eval -
df = [{'A': {'value': '1'}, 'B': {'value': '2'}}]